# Would this be a good scenario to combine MongoDB and Redis?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, nosql

I'm developing a site with Node.js which has many realtime features. One feature is, that users can publish something in a certain channel and this will be immediately pushed to everyone watching the same channel.

I am trying to figure out the best way to approach this. The data structure of MongoDB fits my needs very well, but Redis Pub/Sub feature seems extremely fitting for this problem.

So I thought I might store the full dataset in MongoDB and just add a reference in Redis to push it to the neccessary channels. Then the subscriber clients of these channels could read the full data from the MongoDB database.

Does this make sense or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the eternal philosophical question: to solve my problem, should I use 0, 1 or more approaches/tools/technologies. If your data is document oriented and you need that, MongoDB is on candidate. If you're looking fast performance - Redis is a good bet. I'm sure that there are ways to achieve everything you've described using just one of these two, both, none or other technologies.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense. You can use Redis natively or through the socket.io API, and use MongoDB for persistent data.

The only gotcha is to realize that Redis pub/sub does not provide any queuing facility. Redis does not buffer the notifications, they go straight from the publisher socket to the subscriber sockets, in the same event loop iteration. This is fast, but if a subscriber closes its connection, it may lose some items before the connection is established again. The delivery is not guaranteed at all.

However, a subscriber reconnecting after a disconnection could use the MongoDB data to get the items it has missed if required.

Comment: I would mirror the info in the MongoDB database and use Redis for the realtime experience. If a page reload occurs, the app would pull the data from MongoDB. I thought, that I could just not use Redis and use the Socket.IO feature of broadcasting to certain channels and store everything in MongoDB. The data in Redis would just expire after some time So if a writing occurs, the data is broadcasted and stored in MongoDB. This way I would not need Redis. But I fear that this isn't really scalable since I would rely on one Node.js process (am I right?). Or is Redis just redundant in this scenario?